# SQLAlchemy query for returning grouped products from a sale based on timestamp

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So I am a little stuck on coming up with the logic needed to return the following:

```
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Product Name | 2016-05-10 | 2016-05-11 | 2016-05-12 |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Big Chair    |   29.00    |   78.00    |   900.00   |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Small Chair  |   11.00    |   65.00    |   12.00    |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Box of bees  |    5.00    |   20.00    |   80.00    |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+ ...
```

**Here's why** - my current setup in the SQLAlchemy models.py file is (Please refrain from throwing bricks at me if you find it isn't optimal..):

```
class Sale(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sales'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sale_date = Column(DateTime)
    total_price = Column(Numeric(12, 2), default=0)
    products = relationship('Product', secondary='sale_product')

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    price = Column(Numeric(12, 2), default=0)
    sales = relationship('Sale', secondary='sale_product')


class SaleProduct(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sale_product'
    sale_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('sales.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('products.id'), primary_key=True)
    product_quantity = Column(Numeric(12, 1), default=0)
    sale = relationship('Sale', backref=backref("sale_assoc"))
    product = relationship('Product', backref=backref("product_assoc"))
```

However I am struggling to come up with a query which would return the above result or more specifically, an object which I can then use to achieve said result.
I could "hack" this using python for processing, but I think it is more efficient to get Postgres to do the heavy work.

**Here's my thoughts so far:**

I would need to start off by somehow joining the Product and Sale tables while using SaleProduct as a reference point(??) and then ask SQLAlchemy to group the products by name (In this instance the assumption is the names are ALWAYS unique so no two products will have the same name EVER).
But the issue I run into is when I try to figure out how to JOIN on the already grouped products to return the sum of what they cost for each grouping and then separate that into columns with dates.

**To make it clearer:**

1. Can I even achieve the top example output using either Postgres or SQL Alchemy?
2. Is the whole deal REALLY as complicated as I think it is? What am I missing here?
3. Finally - what is the best approach to end up with a way for returning such a result in the first place? Is it better to get the raw data from the database, then manipulate it using python (say, shove the return into dicts or lists and then output "rows" for printing) or should I be using the database itself for such a task?
4. Being very cheeky here, but if someone has spare time, could they provide some sort of mock-up (on a very small scale) of how this would even work? - Not essential, but I'd love to pick through the implementation if at all possible.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is [`crosstab`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS) (a.k.a. "pivot table"). It allows to you turn values in a column into multiple columns.

Let's work backwards and come up with the data we need to give to `crosstab` to give us the result we want:

```
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Product Name | Sale Date  | Total Quantity |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Big Chair    | 2016-05-10 | 29.00          |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Big Chair    | 2016-05-11 | 78.00          |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Big Chair    | 2016-05-12 | 900.00         |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Small Chair  | 2016-05-10 | 11.00          |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Small Chair  | 2016-05-11 | 65.00          |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Small Chair  | 2016-05-12 | 12.00          |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Box of Bees  | 2016-05-10 | 5.00           |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Box of Bees  | 2016-05-11 | 20.00          |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Box of Bees  | 2016-05-12 | 80.00          |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

What query do we write to give us that? Easy, join the three tables and `GROUP BY` the product and date of sale:

```
SELECT
  products.name,
  sale_date::date,
  sum(product_quantity)
FROM
  sales
  JOIN sale_product ON sales.id = sale_id
  JOIN products ON product_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.name, sale_date::date
```

Now we need to pivot the table on the date.

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab($$ <the previous query> $$, $$ SELECT DISTINCT sale_date::date FROM sales ORDER BY sale_date::date DESC LIMIT 3 $$)
AS sales_numbers(product_name text, today int, yesterday int, ereyesterday int);
```

A limitation on this is that the columns, especially the number of columns, must be predefined. To get dynamic columns, you can [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) a dynamically constructed query. Of course, for maximum flexibility you can do the pivot in Python, but it's slightly more efficient to do it in SQL, IMO.

Using this with SQLAlchemy is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you for your time in answering this. I am accepting this answer since it has enough information for me to go ahead and start digging into how this all works. Very informative. Cheers.